# Problem in the inverse kinematic model of a car like vehicle?

Tags: automotive-engineering, modeling, robotics, kinematics

I'm a electrical engineering student and i am building a simulation of a car like vehicle .

As I understand it:

1. The input for the forward kinematic model are the control
   variables and the output is the position of the vehicle
2. The input for the inverse kinematic model is the position of the
   vehicle and the output are the appropriate controls that will make
   that position.

**Am I wrong? Please give me a source or a document that contains the correct inverse kinematic model of a car like vehicle**

Comment: Its a bit useless to build a inverse kinematic model of a car road system, simply because the system isnt deterministic enough. Offcourse making a inverse kinematic system between left front wheel angle is possible if slightly silly

Comment: it's gona be off road simulation i want to give it some waypoint and calculate the controlls that make the transition to the waypoints possible

Comment: @zed_eln I have some experience with this, if it is still an issue add a comment.